# Is it possible to run a single rust file as a script while linking to other libraries without generating cargo projects

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to run a one off rust "script" without going through creating a cargo project for a single run (since I am providing this script to colleagues).

Ideally I could build directly with the command line avoiding creating cargo projects etc.

for instance:

```
use serde_json::Value;
use some_private_packege_i_own_locally_in_another_directory;
fn main() {
  // do some stuff with these packages and die
}
```

I would need to depend on the `serde_json` and my `some_private_packege_i_own_locally_in_another_directory`.

(A bit similar to rust playground I suppose for a single time use)

Something similar to this from the command line would be great:

```
rustc /path/to/main.rs --dependency serde_json, my_package ...
```

Comment: If it's a script, why not ship a binary?

Comment: because I'm generating the code with a UI tool and then want to compile the generated code

Comment: You can run `cargo build -v` to see the exact `rustc` command that cargo runs.

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/cargo-script I think this is what I need

Comment: In command line, after `rustc` compiling you need one more step to  execute the binary. I think a **script** should be simple as only one command, like the effect of `cargo run`.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a dependency with with `extern` flag, and you can specify the location of transitive dependencies, with `-L dependency`. You will have to compile each dependency, and all of it's dependencies manually:

```
// compile all of serde's dependencies
// compile all of hyper's dependencies
// compile serde
// compile hyper
rustc script.rs --crate-type bin -L dependency=~/tmp/deps --extern serde_json=~/tmp/deps/serde_json.rlib --extern hyper=~/tmp/deps/hyper.rlib
```

As you can tell, this would get very difficult, even with two direct dependencies. Instead, you can use [`cargo-script`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-script), which handles all of this for you:

```
cargo install cargo-script
cargo script -D hyper -D serde_json script.rs
```

Comment: thanks, I don't think cargo script works any longer with 1.5. I'm trying cargo play now. getting some strange errors :)

Comment: cargo-script works in 1.50 (which I assume is what you meant), I just tried the example from the readme and it ran fine. There might be edge-cases where it never worked or has broken, but for basic scripts it still works just fine.

Comment: Although if you're not confident in a long-abandoned project there are a bunch of alternatives since then e.g. cargo-eval (a fork of cargo-script), cargo-single, cargo-play, scriptisto, ...

Comment: (and cargo-script will generate an edition 2015 manifest, so there's that. Doesn't mean you can't use it, just means you have to remember to work in edition 2015 semantics).

Comment: There is also [rust-script](https://crates.io/crates/rust-script).